# How do I fix this scanf + while loop function outside of main?

Tags: c

This is currently works fine but is inside my main function

```
while((strcmp(country, "Australia")) && (strcmp(country, "Japan")))
{
    printf("Please select only Australia or Japan");
    scanf("%s", &country);
    case_change(country); // function to lowercase any uppercaseletter //
}
```

How do I put this into a separate function. (basically another .c file) ? 
I tried doing something like this but it keeps giving a segmentation fault.

I also want it to keep repeating until the correct input is entered

```
int main()
{
  printf("Please select only Australia or Japan");  
  scanf("%s", &country);

  char * selection = testing_function(country);
  printf("The country you have selected is %s", selection);
}

int testing_function(char * country) 
{
    while((strcmp(country, "Australia")) && (strcmp(country, "Japan")))
    {
        printf("Please select only Australia or Japan");
        scanf("%s", &country);
        case_change(country);  // function to lowercase any uppercaseletter //
    }
return(country);
}
```

PS: Im still not done with what happens with "country". So I want to keep it as a string, if that makes sense.

Comment: what is `country`  type in `main()` function ? If its a char array then `scanf("%s", &country);` --> `scanf("%s", country);`

Comment: Also return type of `testing_function()` should be `char*` if you are returning like `return(country);` not `int`.

Comment: @achal Yes, it is a char array, specifically char country[10]

Comment: then why `&country` ? It should be `scanf("%s",country);` as array name itself address, so no need to give `&`.

Answer (score 2):

Several problems with your code:

- `testing_function` - cannot return char * while your prototype returns int
- There was no allocation for `country` before you used it which caused segfault. You must make sure `country` is allocated properly before passing it to `testing_function`
- `scanf` function was wrong because you passed in a pointer to pointer to char (`&country`) instead of pointer to char as expected by control string `%s`
- Actually there is no need to return anything, you can just pass in `country` as a char pointer, and modify it inside `testing_function`

Roughly this would work:

```
void testing_function(char * country)
{
    while((strcmp(country, "Australia")) && (strcmp(country, "Japan")))
    {
        printf("Please select only Australia or Japan");
        scanf("%s", country);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char country[1000] = "";

    testing_function(country);
    printf("The country you have selected is %s", country);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! that worked. 

Just wondering, is there a specific reason you chose char `country[1000] = ""; ` instead of simply `char country[1000];`

Comment: that makes sure the character array is initialised properly (rather than having some garbage characters inside it)

Comment: It initializes the 1st character of the array to `'\0'` (e.g. `0` for empty-string) then all remaining elements not specified in the initialization are initialized to zero by default. So it is a simple, convenient way to initialize a character array to be use as a string to all zero (all nul-terminating characters) to avoid an inadvertent failure to terminate (as long as you do not write more than `size-1` chars)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin wouldn't it be easier to just remember that it just initialise the whole character array to 0, ie it's the same as `memset( arr, 0, sizeof(arr) ) ?

Comment: Really makes no difference. [C11 Standard - 6.7.9 Initialization(p21)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p21) It all depends and whether you want to be correct on how the standard defines initialization -- or the end result.